# BAF and LRR calculation and usage

Tags: vcf, ngs, bcftools, allele-frequency

I'm  working with a vcf file, in particular I'm trying to identify a gene duplication in a sequenced genome.

I studied bcftools cnv command, but for this tool is needed a vcf file containing a BAF and LRR values, that there are not present in my vcf file.

And so the first question is, can I calculate them starting from read depth and allele depth? Once that I have calculate BAF and LRR, can I modify the original vcf file inserting the calculated values? To have a vcf file containing BAF and LRR values I have to ask to the geneticist to use particular pipeline in NGS instrument?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.